# Shared connection frequently closes when opening a new connection

Tags: networking, ssh, terminal, remote-desktop

I'm making heavy use of reusing a shared connection which I open to a remote box at the beginning of my workday.

My `.ssh/config` looks somewhat like this:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r

Host remote
HostName login.remote.com
User username
ForwardX11 yes
ServerAliveInterval 300
```

This works rather nicely with one exception. After establishing a first connection (*master connection*) this works fine: I can use the terminal with the *master connection* to do stuff on the remote and I can reuse the *master connection* in a new terminal by calling `ssh remote`, which opens a new connection without the need to retype my credentials.

However, if some time has passed (between tens of minutes and hours, I'm not really sure) and I want to open a new connection, this fails and the *master connection* closes with the message (on the *master* terminal):

```
Connection to login.remote.com closed by remote host.
Connection to login.remote.com closed.
```

and (on the terminal I'm using to open a new connection)

```
Shared connection to login.remote.com closed.
```

although it was working perfectly fine just seconds ago (I could execute commands on the remote using the terminal running the *master connection*.

**EDIT:**: This is the `ssh -vvv remote` output for a newly opened session which fails to open properly:

> OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/config
>   debug1: /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/config line 27: Applying options for remote
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>   debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
>   debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
>   debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
>   debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
>   debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
>   debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
>   debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 23500
>   debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
>   debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 5
>   debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
>   debug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly
>   Shared connection to login.remote.com closed.

This seems kind of odd to me and I suppose it's either a bug or a misconfiguration, can you help out?

Answer (score 0):

Disable these options in ssh config:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

Make the value of `ServerAliveInterval` sufficiently small:

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
```